# Visual Studios 2013 getting the Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I'm building a website using Visual studio 2013 and I'm stuck at making the user register and once submitted the details is stored in a database and the manager can log in and view all registered accounts. however I'm getting

```
Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.
```

BTW table is the name of the database table I'm storing the registered accounts data into.

any help is appropriated!

this is the code for the submit button

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Registration :
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString-reg"].ConnectionString); //connects to regstration DB//
                conn.Open(); //to open connection to DB
                String checkuser = "select count(*) from Table where Name= '"+ nameBox.Text +"'"; // checks wether the name entered is in the database already //
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); 
                if (temp == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write("User already exists");
                } 
                conn.Close(); //to close connection to DB after executing a query//
            }
            catch (SqlException Ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error:" + Ex.ToString());
            } 
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString-reg"].ConnectionString); //connects to regstration DB//
            conn.Open(); //to open connection to DB
            String insertQuery = "insert into Table (Name, Date of birth, Yoga experience, Health issues, Email address, Telephone number, Password) values (@Name, @dob, @exp, @health, @email, @phone, @password)"; // inserts into table and declares data as variables// 
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nameBox.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", Yeardropdown.SelectedItem.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expe", expBox.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@health", healthBox.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailBox.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phoneBox.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwrd", passwrdBox.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("Thank you, Your registration has been successfull!");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void Daydropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

two things:

1) you have used table as table name. As it's already a keyword in SQL, so change this name. Though you can use following command:

```
Insert into [Table]....
```

2) Your column name contains spaces, so it probably will cause some error. Use bracket around your column names if they contains spaces.

```
String insertQuery = "insert into Table (Name, [Date of birth], [Yoga experience], [Health issues], [Email address], [Telephone number], Password) values (@Name, @dob, @exp, @health, @email, @phone, @password)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is why you need to check `IsPostBack`?

First `Table` in `SQL` will be a `Table` syntax.

If you must use the syntax as the name....

Microsoft SQL Server
Amend your SQL query from `table` to `[table]`

It should be working..

Have you run your code in SQL Management Studio ?
I believe you will hit error if you try to `insert` or `select` using that query

Syntax as Name your must Add []

Comment: I'm fairly  new to this but I'm sure it should work as I've followed the tutorial with no mistakes, not sure why this is happening :(

Answer (score 0):

we can't use table as table name in sqlserver,
change your table name, and it will works and dont forget to change your table name in query too.

```
 String insertQuery = "insert into changethistablename (Name, Date of birth, Yoga experience, Health issues, Email address, Telephone number, Password) values (@Name, @dob, @exp, @health, @email, @phone, @password)"; // inserts into table and declares data as variables// 
 String checkuser = "select count(*) from changethistablename where Name= '"+ nameBox.Text +"'"; // checks wether the name entered is in the database already //
```